# Preventing NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

```
public void arrayPrint() {
    for(String i : array) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }           
}
```

I can't figure out a way so that in arrayPrint, it can prevent NullPointerException from happening. The error keeps occurring for test5. I tried to add the if statement:

```
public void arrayPrint() {
    for(String i : array) {
        if(i != null){
           System.out.println(i);
      }
   }           
}
```

But it keeps giving the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Task.printArray(Task.java:11)
at Task.main(Task.java:38)
```

Line 11 is the for loop in arrayPrint() and line 38 is test5.arrayPrint();
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `for(String i : array) {` is translated by the compiler to something like:

```
for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    String i = array[j];
    ...
```

and it fails on `array.length` when `array` is null.

For more information see [*JLS §14.14.2*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `String` `i` is already a member of the `array` object. What you need to do is check if the `array` object itself is `null`.

In order to fix this, you will want to verify that `array` itself is not `null`.

```
public void arrayPrint() {
    if(array != null){
        for(String i : array) {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
   }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to blow up, you'll have to do something like this:

```
public void arrayPrint()
{
    if (array != null)
    {
        for(String i : array)
        {
            if(i != null)
            {
               System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```